# Writing bash arguments with trunctation

Tags: bash, scripting, text-formatting, unicode

I want to print the first two arguments of a bash function, with the unicode character `\u2263` on each side using a two space separation.  The thing is that the final unicode must display at column 70.  If the character region where `$1` and `$2` reaches column 68, the
excess characters are truncated.

```
         1         2         3   V     4         5         6         7
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

 U  FIRST-ARG                                            SECOND-ARG  U
 U  FIRST-ARG-LONGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG                        SECOND-ARG  U
```

I could specify a column number (example choosing `34`, depicted by character `V`) to be the maximum width possible for `FIRST-ARG`

Have started with using max lengths of `cl` and `cr`.

```
local cl=34 cr=30
printf ' \u2263  %.${cl}s   %.${cr}s  \u2263\n' "$1" "$2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get 2 long parameters:

```bash
set -- '123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.' '987654321.987654321.987654321.987654321.'
```

Let's say we want to set V at 40, so we have 40 chars of field1 and 68-40=28 chars for field2

```bash
cl=40
cr=$((68-cl))
```

Now we want to print the first field left-justified and the second right-justified (although that won't be visible with these long parameters). It's not enough to set the field widths in the printf format string, we also need to take only a substring of the parameters:

```bash
printf '\u2263  %-*s%*s  \u2263\n' "$cl" "${1:0:cl}" "$cr" "${2:0:cr}"
```

```
≣  123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.987654321.987654321.98765432  ≣
```

We can see

- "123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.", the first 40 chars of the first parameter, and
- "987654321.987654321.98765432", the first 28 chars of the second.

Comment: I am getting a slight problem with the second argument as it is being printed on the second line.

Comment: I have identified the problem. why cannot I do `local cl=40 cr=$((68-cl))` in a single line?

Comment: Because the arithmetic expression is evaluated before the variable assignments. This is documented in the manual: [Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion)

Comment: Should this be the correct behaviour, or should it be considered a bug?

Comment: Is the comment you are referring to in item 1 ?

Comment: bash is behaving as documented: not a bug.

Comment: Here, the command name is "local". #1 does not apply (there are no assignments before the command name). #2 applies (the arithmetic expression is expanded, using an undefined variable). #3 does not apply (no redirections). #4 does not apply (same reason as #1). Finally, the "local" command executes.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in `bash`, `printf`'s `%-63.63s` pads with spaces and truncates to 63 *bytes* not characters, so can't be used for formatting / aligning unless all characters are single byte. 99.99% of characters are encoded on more than one byte in UTF-8. Your U+2263 character is encoded on 3 bytes in UTF-8, 4 bytes in GB18030.

bash's `${var:offset:length}`, like ksh93's where it copied it from works at character level, but even then that only works if all characters are single-width.

To align text properly, possible approaches are to:

1. use padding/truncation operators that take into  account  the display width of characters.
2. assuming the output goes to a terminal, use control sequences to tell the terminal to write what you want at the write place and erase what you don't want.

For 1, you could use a shell such as ksh93 or zsh that has builtin operators for that instead of bash.

In zsh:

```
align() printf ' \u2263  %s  \u2263\n' ${(j[  ]mr[63])@}
```

The `r[length]` parameter expansion flag (here short for `r[length][ ]` as space is the default padding characters) `r`ight pads to the given length, and with `m`, that length is in terms of display width.

Or to left-align (and right-pad) `$1` and right-align `$2`, as you later clarified:

```
align() printf ' \u2263  %s  \u2263\n' "${(mr[31])1} ${(ml[31])2}"
```

With `ksh93`, it's even simpler:

```
align() printf ' \u2263  %-63.63Ls  \u2263\n' "$1  $2"
```

Where `%Ls` as opposed to `%s` takes a string of characters, not bytes and pads and truncates based on their display width.

Or to left-align `$1` and right-align `$2`:

```
align() printf ' \u2263  %-31.31Ls %31.31Ls  \u2263\n' "$1" "$2"
```

Note that those don't work if the input contains control characters.

For 2, you could: disable auto-margins, write the whole text, move to column 68 and write `"  ≣"` and erase the rest:

```
am_off=$(tput rmam) am_on=$(tput smam)
col68=$(tput cr; tput cuf 68)
del_to_eol=$(tput el)
align() {
  printf ' \u2263  %s\u2263%s\n' "$am_off$1  $2$col68  " "$del_to_eol$am_on"
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Huh? What do you need?

If the question is how to manipulate string length, then you can use string functions described here:
https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

If you need to print something in formatted way - you can use `printf` instead of `echo`. It uses the very same formatting as `printf()` in C. https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf